# Dropwn list menu open behind of other Views in SwiftUi

Tags: swiftui, dropdown, z-index

When I make dropdown list menu in SwiftUi, dropdown list shows behind of other Component View, I've tried to zIndex(1) at the last of the VStack, and I've tried .overlay at the top of the Stack but it didn't solve my problem, I've shared below  code and I've shared screenshot of the problem, how can I solve this problem? thanks...

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

    struct DropdownOption: Hashable {
        let key: String
        let value: String
        
        public static func == (lhs: DropdownOption, rhs: DropdownOption) -> Bool {
            return lhs.key == rhs.key
        }
    }
    
    struct DropdownRow: View {
        var option: DropdownOption
        var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
        
        var body: some View {
            Button(action: {
                if let onOptionSelected = self.onOptionSelected {
                    onOptionSelected(self.option)
                }
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Text(self.option.value)
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
        }
    }
    
    struct Dropdown: View {
        var options: [DropdownOption]
        var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
        
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(self.options, id: \.self) { option in
                        DropdownRow(option: option, onOptionSelected: self.onOptionSelected)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(minHeight: CGFloat(options.count) * 30, maxHeight: 250)
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
            )
        }
    }
    
    struct DropdownSelector: View {
        @State private var shouldShowDropdown = false
        @State private var selectedOption: DropdownOption? = nil
        var placeholder: String
        var options: [DropdownOption]
        var onOptionSelected: ((_ option: DropdownOption) -> Void)?
        private let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 45
        
        var body: some View {
            Button(action: {
                self.shouldShowDropdown.toggle()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Text(selectedOption == nil ? placeholder : selectedOption!.value)
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .foregroundColor(selectedOption == nil ? Color.gray: Color.black)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image(systemName: self.shouldShowDropdown ? "arrowtriangle.up.fill" : "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 9, height: 5)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 9, weight: .medium))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .frame(width: .infinity, height: self.buttonHeight)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .overlay(
                VStack {
                    if self.shouldShowDropdown {
                        Spacer(minLength: buttonHeight + 10)
                        Dropdown(options: self.options, onOptionSelected: { option in
                            shouldShowDropdown = false
                            selectedOption = option
                            self.onOptionSelected?(option)
                        })
                    }
                }, alignment: .topLeading
            )
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).fill(Color.white)
            )
        }
    }
```

calling DropDownList

```
ZStack(alignment:.top){
                    HStack {
                        Group {
                            DropdownSelector(
                                placeholder: "Choose Aircraft Type",
                                options: options,
                                onOptionSelected: { option in
                                    print(option)
                                })
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                            
                        }
                    }.padding(.top, 50)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Group {
                            DropdownSelector(
                                placeholder: "Choose Simulator Type",
                                options: optionsSimulator,
                                onOptionSelected: { option in
                                    print(option)
                                })
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                            
                        }
                    }.padding(.top, 50)
}
```

Comment: Put drop down in ScrollView overlay and disable scroll view till drop down is closed.

Comment: @Asperi thanks your answer, I tried it and it works, I shared screen shot, but I have another problem, all drop down lists open at the same time, I want to close other dropdown When other drop down list is open